# If $u \in L^p$ and $\Delta u \in L^p$ as well, do we necessarily have $u \in W^{2,p}$ for $1<p<\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, laplacian, regularity-theory-of-pdes

This kind of question has always confused me, I need to confirm if I am right..

Let $S^1$ be the circle and consider $u \in L^p(S^1)$ for $1<p<\infty$.

If $\Delta u$ is a well-defined measurable function via the formula
\begin{equation}
\int_{S^1} \phi \Delta u = \int_{S^1} u \Delta \phi \text{ for all } \phi \in C^\infty(S^1)
\end{equation}
and in fact $\Delta u \in L^p(S^1)$, then is it necessarily true that
\begin{equation}
u \in W^{2,p}(S^1)
\end{equation}
holds?

I am quite sure this is the case, but I cannot provide correctly. I know that $\Delta$ is essentially self-adjoint, but do not see how this fact is used here.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Should be the case. Look up for regularity theorems for elliptic PDE. Your $u$ is a solution to the equation $\Delta u =f$, with $f$ in $L^p$. You want to infer extra regularity for $u$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro PDE textbooks like Evans do not seem to deal with cases other than $p=2$. So I am not certain..

Answer (score 2):

In the $\mathbb S^1$ case this is rather obvious. Let $\theta$ be the angular coordinate, so that $\Delta=\partial_\theta^2$. Therefore the assumptions read $u\in L^p$ and $\partial_\theta^2 u\in L^p$. Which, by definition, means that $u\in W^{2, p}$.

This kind of questions become harder when you have more than one coordinate, i.e. on higher dimensional domains. There, it is not obvious that having a control on the Laplacian $\Delta= \partial_{x_1}^2+\ldots+\partial_{x_n}^2$ implies a control on the single derivatives $\partial_{x_1}^2, \partial_{x_2}^2, \ldots, \partial_{x_n}^2$.

Comment: Oh I see..so you are saying that $u \in W^{2,p}$ is NOT true for "multivariable" cases?

Comment: But, it does seem true, cf. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335952/domain-of-definition-of-laplace-operator-on-l2

Comment: Oh no, of course it is true. I mean, in this one variable case it is true AND OBVIOUS. In the multivariable case it is true AND HARD. Hope I made myself clearer now, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your clarification. I also know somehow vaguely that it is true. But I cannot find a reference explicitingly proving this issue..